# Gulp browser-sync reloads only the first time a file is saved

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I start it off with

```
gulp sync
```

and get

```
[17:14:23] Starting 'scripts'...
[17:14:23] Finished 'scripts' after 43 ms
[17:14:23] Starting 'sync'...
[17:14:23] Finished 'sync' after 20 ms
[BS] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:(my port)
    External: http://(my internal IP address)
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:(myport+n)
 UI External: http://(my internal IP address)
 --------------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: public
```

The browser loads up the page.

I save a file and it works. Terminal output :

```
[17:17:22] Starting 'scripts'...
[17:17:22] Finished 'scripts' after 17 ms
[17:17:22] Starting 'scripts-watch'...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
```

I save the file again (or save a different file)

```
[17:18:38] Starting 'scripts'...
[17:18:38] Finished 'scripts' after 8.99 ms
```

Note theres no Reloading Browsers message. The browser does not reload. Stopping gulp and manually reloading the page DOES reflect the change.

My gulpfle :

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var react = require('gulp-react');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();


gulp.task('less', function() {
    return gulp.src('dev/less/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(rename('styles.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))

});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('dev/js/*.js')
        .pipe(rename('scripts.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});

gulp.task('build', function() {
    return gulp.src('dev/components/**')
        .pipe(concat('components.min.js'))
        .pipe(react())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'))
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.start('less');
    gulp.start('scripts');
    gulp.start('build');
});

gulp.task('scripts-watch', ['scripts'], browserSync.reload);
gulp.task('less-watch', ['less'], browserSync.reload);
gulp.task('build-watch', ['build'], browserSync.reload);

gulp.task('sync', ['scripts'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "public",
            index : "index.htm"
        }
    });

    gulp.watch('dev/js/*.js', ['scripts-watch', browserSync.reload]);
    gulp.watch('dev/less/*.less', ['less-watch', browserSync.reload]);
    gulp.watch('dev/components/**', ['build-watch', browserSync.reload]);
});
```

Using chrome on ubuntu if that matters.